Microsoft SSO token based validation for my spring boot API's
I’m currently working on implementing token-based authentication using Microsoft Single Sign-On (SSO) via Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for my Spring Boot microservices. I’ve outlined the steps involved but would appreciate any additional guidance or tips from the community.
Here’s a brief overview of what I’m trying to achieve:
Azure AD Setup:
Creating an Azure AD Tenant and registering the application.
Configuring Certificates & Secrets and API Permissions.
Spring Boot Configuration:
Adding dependencies for Spring Security and OAuth2.
Configuring OAuth2 client settings in application.yml or application.properties.
Setting up security configurations to handle OAuth2 login.
Microservices Integration:
Ensuring token validation across microservices, including public key sharing and using JwtDecoder.
Testing and Debugging:
Testing the setup locally and troubleshooting issues.
I’ve followed the general steps but am facing some challenges with token validation and configuration across multiple microservices. If anyone has experience with this setup or can provide insights, suggestions, or examples, I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
I’ve followed the general steps but am facing some challenges with token validation and configuration across multiple microservices.
